# How do I one shot or use any shortcut key to "qualify the variables" with `this` keyword in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I have a class which I need to add in new methods etc.  However, since it doesn't have a POJO so Eclipse IDE is asking to add in "qualifying with `this`" but there are so many variables and I find right-clicking on each of them is taking up too much time.

[image]
So, I hope someone can tell me if there is a short-cut that can do it once and for all.

Answer (score 0):

There is no magic that will just fix all the errors.  However, you can reduce the pain of this by using keyboard shortcuts, instead of using the mouse.

Use the keyboard to move the mouse over each symbol with the red squiggle, and press Ctrl+1, which should be bound to "quick-fix". The first choice will be highlighted, which is likely the suggestion to add "this.", so just press Enter.  Then use the keyboard again to move to the next one, and so on.